# factoring out client side code in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, refactoring, client-side

So, I know node.js, but I'm learning how to socket.io and express.js, (just started express/socket a few hours ago).

This isn't a huge issue, but I like my code to be clean, and I'm trying to factor out my client side code so it's just in a script tag as a src. For example, on my index.html page I have the following:

```
..
<head>
    <title>Example Title</title>
    <link href="./styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="./scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Where ./scripts/index.js is the javascript code for index.html. It looks like

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");

document.getElementById("sendBox").submit = function() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("m");socket.emit("chat message", msg.value);
    msg.value = "";
    return false;
};
```

All the routing is working, but now the problem is that I'm getting the error "ReferenceError: io is not defined" when I try to use the code. On socket.io's website, their example always just has a script tag with all of their page specific code embedded within it. I think that's ugly and means I have to edit an html page to edit my js for a page. This is especially annoying when the highlighting and autocorrects in my editor align to html on an html file, not js. It's not a catastrophic thing, I COULD embed my code like socket.io shows in their examples, but I'd prefer not to.

for those confused by what i mean, Socket.io's beginner example code:

```
<head>
  <title>Socket.IO Chat</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script> // This is the code i want to look more like ^
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  </script> // End of the code I'd like to factor out.
```

To sum up, how can i make the variable "io" available to my index.js script?

Thanks

Comment: Is this correct: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" ...>` ? This would reference the directory 'socket.io' in your server's document root. Check the browser's debugger (F12) Net panel to see if `socket.io.js` is loaded.

Comment: Actually, socket.io is a bit weird, but they make their script available at that place specifically, so no matter where your webroot is located, that path will get you to their script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try swapping the js script tags

```
<head>
    <title>Example Title</title>
    <link href="./styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

the way you had it, it would try to run io before it was loaded